# Run powershell.exe with script body as param and other params

Tags: powershell, command-line

I need to run windows powershell script from my programm. To do that, I just start powershell process with a string arg which contains script body itself:

```
 Process.Start("powershell.exe", "my script body..");
```

and it works. But I also need to pass some args to script. It should look like :

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "some args my script body..");
```

- this is a problem. I know that it is possible. I evend found [description](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315276.aspx), but there is no such example there. Help, please

Answer (score 2):

from [the doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb%28v=vs.80%29.aspx),
you should be able to do something like :

```
process.Start("powershell.exe","-noprofile -file c:\temp\test.ps1 TEST -noexit")
```

where TEST is the argument passed to the script

edit after re reading your question :

```
process.Start("powershell.exe","-noprofile -command {write-host $args[0] } -args 'test'")
```

Answer (score 0):

Working solution :

```
Process.Start("powershell.exe", "-noexit -command &{write-host $args[0]} arg1Value arg2Value");
```